# FBSDKGraphRequestConnection requestConnectionDidFinishLoading never called

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to make a batch call to Open Graph.
Here's my code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequestConnection * connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
for (NSString * userID in userIDArray) {

     FBSDKGraphRequest * request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:userID parameters:nil];

     [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

         if (!error) {
               NSLog(@"%@ added", friend);
         }
         else {
               NSLog(@"error when fetching friend's detail:%@", error);
         }

     }];

}

connection.delegate = self;
[connection start];
```

I have confirmed my class to the protocol:

```
@interface MYClass : NSObject <FBSDKGraphRequestConnectionDelegate>
```

and in my `.m` I have implemented the delegate methods:

```
- (void)requestConnectionDidFinishLoading:(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"requestConnectionDidFinishLoading");
}

- (void)requestConnectionWillBeginLoading:(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"requestConnectionWillBeginLoading");
}

- (void)requestConnection:(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}
```

The delegate method `requestConnectionDidFinishLoading` is never called even when all the requests are finished, while the other two work fine.

Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: I had exactly the same situation when I used 4.0 sdk, they fixed this in 4.1 (April 30th) sdk.
the problem was when the facebook app was jumping back to my app - in openURL the FBSDKApplicationDelegate's openURL function returned false meaning it refused to handle it as a proper facebook deeplink. anyways, it's fixed now.